# Does using Facebook Analytics (for Apps) require me to update my privacy policy?

Tags: analytics, facebook, privacy-policy

As the topic says: Do I need to update my Apps privacy policy if I integrate Facebook Analytics? I can't find anything searching the Web or Facebook's documentation. It only states all data collected gets anonymised, but there is no how or if it affects privacy policy. And, if so, is there a template?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely **yes** because you need to follow the rules and guidelines from [Facebook's Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). Here is Section "2. Give people control":

[image: Facebook Platform Policy via TermsFeed]

There is no mention of a Privacy Policy requirement in the documentation of Facebook Analytics, but the Platform Policy is for all developers in addition to policies specific to individual Facebook products.

Most [analytics SDKs have the Privacy Policy requirement](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-analytics-sdk/) - Google Analytics, Mixpanel, Flurry etc. - in their terms and policies agreements that developers must agree to.

Here's an example from Mixpanel where developers are informed that they must have a Privacy Policy and that the policy must inform end-users how they can opt-out of Mixpanel:

[image: Mixpanel Opt-out clause requirement screenshot via TermsFeed]

Comment: So in order to write a privacy policy the question is, which and how data is actually collected by Facebook? How does Facebook expect me to come up with a privacy policy without ellaborating on data collection?

Comment: Annotation: In case of FB Analytics the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/quickstart-android) speaks of app events: "App events are the key actions that people take, such as launching your app, viewing content or making a purchase." Let's say I captured these exact events, would it be sufficient to mention them like this (e.g. "viewing content") in a privacy policy?